# Disable execution of chunk with R markdown eval variable

Tags: r, r-markdown, eval

I am trying to define a set of variables to control on/off of the execution of chunks in my Rmarkdown. However, I noticed that with the `variable1 = FALSE` and `{r chunk1, eval = variable1}`, the chunk will be still executed (by hitting "Run All Chunks" button). For knitting, this approach works, and the chunk will not be evaluated. Is there anything that I have missed.

For example, the following Rmarkdown will execute `pressure1` and plot the pressure with `eval = varaible1`, but `eval =FALSE` worked for `pressure2` and disable the chunk.

[image]

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r switches, include=FALSE}
variable1 = FALSE
```

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

```{r pressure1, eval=variable1}
print("pressure1")
plot(pressure)
```

```{r pressure2, eval=FALSE}
print("pressure2")
plot(pressure)
```
````

Comment: I cannot reproduce your bug. When I run it, I see the code chunks that include `print("pressure...")`, but not the output from them. If you want to hide them as well, consider `eval=variable1, include=variable1`.

Comment: Said differently, the three chunk options `echo`, `include`, and `eval` are all orthogonal: the first defines whether you see the code ("input"); second to see the code "output"; third if you want it to evaluate at all (which does affect `include=`, but by side-effect). Since `eval=` can also be numeric (which expression(s) to evaluate), `include=` can still be distinct from a non-true `eval`. (Source: https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#code-evaluation)

Comment: @r2evans maybe this is not a bug, and I am trying to understand the reason. `variable1=FALSE` did not turn off chunk `pressure1` and it is still evaluated, executed, please see the updated screenshot.

Comment: It did turn off its evaluation, just not printing the code (that was not evaluated) in the rendering. I did not see it executed (no printed anything, no plot).

Comment: Just to confirm, and sorry for the confusion in the question. I believe knit will show no plots, but so you did not see any plot at all by hitting "Run All Chunks" button. Not from `pressure1` and not from `pressure2` either?

Comment: You're showing it in RStudio, in a non-standard knitting environment. It appears that when you tell RStudio to eval a block, it ignores the `eval=` expression in the chunk header. When I said I could not reproduce, I merely used `rmarkdown::render` ... and I saw zero plots, zero `print`ed things.

Comment: Similarly, if you use `echo=FALSE`, RStudio is *still* going to show you the code, so realize that "RStudio notebook != rendering environment". Most of `eval=`, `include=`, and `eval=` is intended for the automated rendering, not manual.

Comment: That makes sense. But this feature is a bit troublesome since sometimes I need to run a certain set of chunks for particular data, and some chunks will break the workflow. Is there a work around? Also, it does not ignore `eval=FALSE`, which is explicit.

Comment: RStudio is ignoring `eval=` when in manual notebook mode, so ... No. However, if you have known conditions where the code in the chunk should not execute, I suggest you wrap the chunk code in a simple `if`. For a contrived example, if the code should not run unless a variable is present and a frame, then the chunk could be `if (exists("someframe") && inherits(someframe, "data.frame") && nrow(someframe) > 0) { ...chunk_code_here... }`.